# Taxonomy dropdown to match the related content (in a views with exposed filters)

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

## Goal

Each time I select a term from the select all the related articles in the page will be listed. The correct link is terms/term-name (taxonomy term alias)

e.g terms/sports will display all sports articles

How do I alter the form submit link?

[image]

## Achieved so far

I created master display with 'exposed form in block: Yes'
The block is shown up with all the terms I need in the select widget.
Now when I select a term from the dropdown the url turns to terms?tid=54 displaying a page with the link to the terms/term-name. but I want to access directly.

All I need is to display at once from the select all the related content

Answer (score 0):

Create a View with Block display from Taxonomy Terms and at Format Tab choose Jump Menu. If you need to overwrite the Jump Menu path you need to add a custom text field and create your desire path out of Replacement Patterns.

Than select the created custom text field from Jump Menu path settings

Comment: Thanks, it works however it seems the select elements are overwritten too.